# using Thread with ToggleButton and onFocusChange

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I currently need a while loop for my toggleButton because the toggleButton is an essential part of my app where it will need to be constantly checked so that my EditText can be reflected accordingly. I tried this thread code, but the UI gets locked up when it ran.

My thread code is:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.selectionmode2);

        Thread whileLoop = new Thread(){
            public void run(){

                toggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
                {

                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                            boolean isChecked) {

                        String row1TextContains = row1TextField.getText().toString().trim();
                        String row2TextContains = row2TextField.getText().toString().trim();
                        String row3TextContains = row3TextField.getText().toString().trim();
                        String row4TextContains = row4TextField.getText().toString().trim();
                        while(isChecked)
                        {
                            if(row1TextField.isFocused())
                            {


                                row2TextField.setEnabled(false);
                                row2TextField.setHint("Disabled");
                                //toggleButton.setChecked(true);
                            }else
                            {
                                row1TextField.setEnabled(true);
                                row2TextField.setEnabled(true);
                                row2TextField.setHint(row2Hint);
                                row3TextField.setEnabled(true);
                                row4TextField.setEnabled(true);
                            } 
                            if(row2TextField.isFocused())
                            {
                                row3TextField.setEnabled(false);
                                row3TextField.setHint("Disabled");
                                toggleButton.setChecked(true);
                            }else
                            {
                                row3TextField.setHint(row3Hint);
                                row3TextField.setEnabled(true);
                            }
                            if(row3TextField.isFocused())
                            {

                                row4TextField.setEnabled(false);
                                row4TextField.setHint("Disabled");
                                if(row1TextContains.isEmpty() || row1TextContains.length() == 0 || row1TextContains.equals(""))
                                {
                                    row2TextField.setEnabled(true);
                                }else
                                {
                                    row2TextField.setEnabled(false);
                                    row2TextField.setHint("Disabled");
                                }

                            }else{
                                row4TextField.setEnabled(true);
                                row4TextField.setHint(row4Hint);
                            }
                            if(row4TextField.isFocused())

                            {
                                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Row 4 of Large Character is not allowed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                                toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                                toast.show();
                                row4TextField.setHint("Disabled");
                                row1TextField.requestFocus();

                            }
                        }

                    }

                });

            }
        };

        whileLoop.start();
```

I initially used a custom method and `onFocusChange` to check the button status and change my `EditText` accordingly. But I feel that, if I were to use a thread with a while loop constantly checking my button, it will work smoother and will have lesser problems.

How do I integrate my custom method onRowFocus and onFocusChange with the setCheckedOnChangedListener in the UI thread as to prevent it from locking? Is it possible or is that all redundant?

```
private void checkRowFocus(View v){

        String row1TextContains = row1TextField.getText().toString().trim();
        String row2TextContains = row2TextField.getText().toString().trim();
        String row3TextContains = row3TextField.getText().toString().trim();
        String row4TextContains = row4TextField.getText().toString().trim();
        if(v == row1TextField)
        {


            row2TextField.setEnabled(false);
            row2TextField.setHint("Disabled");
            //toggleButton.setChecked(true);
        }else
        {
            row1TextField.setEnabled(true);
            row2TextField.setEnabled(true);
            row2TextField.setHint(row2Hint);
            row3TextField.setEnabled(true);
            row4TextField.setEnabled(true);
        } 
        if(v == row2TextField)
        {
            row3TextField.setEnabled(false);
            row3TextField.setHint("Disabled");
            toggleButton.setChecked(true);
        }else
        {
            row3TextField.setHint(row3Hint);
            row3TextField.setEnabled(true);
        }
        if(v == row3TextField)
        {

            row4TextField.setEnabled(false);
            row4TextField.setHint("Disabled");
            if(row1TextContains.isEmpty() || row1TextContains.length() == 0 || row1TextContains.equals(""))
            {
                row2TextField.setEnabled(true);
            }else
            {
                row2TextField.setEnabled(false);
                row2TextField.setHint("Disabled");
            }

        }else{
            row4TextField.setEnabled(true);
            row4TextField.setHint(row4Hint);
        }
        if(v == row4TextField)

        {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Row 4 of Large Character is not allowed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            toast.show();
            row4TextField.setHint("Disabled");
            row1TextField.requestFocus();

        }

    }

@Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

        boolean statusOn = toggleButton.isChecked();
        String row1TextContains = row1TextField.getText().toString().trim();
        String row2TextContains = row2TextField.getText().toString().trim();
        String row3TextContains = row3TextField.getText().toString().trim();
        String row4TextContains = row4TextField.getText().toString().trim();


        if(statusOn)
        {

            checkRowFocus(v);


        }if(!statusOn)
        {


            row1TextField.setEnabled(true);
            row1TextField.setHint(row1Hint);
            if(row1TextContains.isEmpty() || row1TextContains.length() == 0 || row1TextContains.equals("")){
                row2TextField.setEnabled(true);
                row2TextField.setHint(row2Hint);
            }else
            {
                row2TextField.setEnabled(false);
            }

            row3TextField.setEnabled(true);
            row3TextField.setHint(row3Hint);
            row4TextField.setEnabled(true);
            row4TextField.setHint(row4Hint);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are inviting ANR dialog with this code.

Comment: You shouldn't be setting a listener repeatedly in code. The point of a listener is that it will be invoked when the state changes removing the need for polling. If you need to know when the view gains focus as well as when it changes you can set a onFocusChangeListener as well. Take the code you have but remove it from the new thread.

Comment: Why would you want to use a Loop for polling a button state? You can register a listener?

Comment: Is it possible then to put a togglebutton `setOnCheckedChangedListener` in a `onFocusChange`? Because I tried that and I can't retrieve the View because the params is only applied to `onFocusChange` not the `setOnCheckedChangedListener`.

Comment: These are not the droids you are looking for. Why would you want to set the listener inside onFocusChange?